# How to display saved data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `table`, I want to refresh it without reloading the whole page. so, how can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myController as vm">
  //My Grid here...  
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.save = function(obj){
   //here is save the data
}
```

Now I need to display saved data in my grid without reloading.

Comment: Angular do this. Please share more code or detail your problem

Comment: just change value `vm.orderDetail`

Comment: two-way data binding. if your value is changed - div block will be updated automatically.

Comment: i have a Grid inside <div></div> @Alexis

Comment: And what about your JS code ? Where do you init your orderDetail ?

Comment: i load whole order related detail on page load i mean under activate() function. @Alexis

Comment: The pseudo code you have posted is misleading for the question your asking. Everyone is correctly advising you to just update your model and angulars bindings will deal with the rest. However if a simple binding like that is not what your actually doing you should post your JS and HTML code that reflects what your trying to achieve. IE show how your building your Grid, how your currently populating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in that case, what can be done is:

Inside your `$scope.save` function call another function `getSavedData()` which will get all the data.

Like:

```
$scope.save = function(obj){
  //save code goes here...
  getSavedData(); //after save.. and bind it to your $scope varibale 
}
```

**Thanks (Answered own question)**

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is totally absurd from the viewpoint of Angular.js. Angular is itself used so that $scope binds the values from controller to view and you never need to refresh. So your question in itself is contradicting.

What you might have meant is to send and recieve json values and updating them in view after some dealy or at some point in time. For that you have to run your service again from Service/Factory and as soon as you get result, bind them in Controller with your model.

Comment: You need to update json and bind to model, not refresh the div bro. And, otherwise update your question to show why you need to refresh div? Div never refreshes, either whole page refreshes, or json values is updated after json call.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it in your controller using scope variable, like below:

```
app.controller('yourcontroller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.orderDetail = "some value";
});
```